# Why is InferSharp saying "Memory becomes unreachable" in my EF/Linq method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, infer#

I am running a static analyzer ([InferSharp](https://github.com/microsoft/infersharp)) that keeps warning me that this will not properly close the resource as it gives me the same error [as in this Microsoft blog article that introduces Infer# with examples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/slaying-zombie-no-repo-crashes-with-infersharp/):

```
public List<Results>? GetAllBySampleUniqueId(Guid uniqueId)
{
    using AppDb db = new();
    
    Sample? dbSample = db.Samples.Include(x => x.Results)
        .Include(x => x.Animal)
        .Include(x => x.Customer)
        .Include(x => x.SessionRecord)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UniqueId == uniqueId);
    
    if (dbSample == null)
    {
        Logging.CurrentLogger.Debug("No Results exist for sample with uid {Sample.UniqueId}", uniqueId);
        return null;
    }
    
    List<Results> dbResults = dbSample.Results;
    Logging.CurrentLogger.Debug("Obtained {Results.Count} Results for sample with uid {Sample.UniqueId}", dbResults.Count, uniqueId);
    return dbResults;
}
```

Sadly I don't fully understand the difference between the sample in the article and mine, as mine is a repo and their is a direct resource call. So will this call cause a memory leak? I don't think so since the using statement should terminate it.

The error is specifically: *"Memory becomes unreachable at `return dbresults`"*.

Comment: I'm not sure about the defaut behaviour of EF Core (I mainly use EF on .Net Framework) and if I understand you question. If your Sample object uses lazy load to fill the navigators (Animal, Customer and SessionRecord) you cannot dispose db and ask for Animal, Customer or SessionRecord afterwards because theses calls will require a non disposed db to answer. You can detect the use of lazy load: if the actual class of the sample Object is not "Sample" but a proxy class, you are using lazy loading.

Comment: You do not need so many includes. Leave only one `Include(x => x.Results)` and query will be faster.

Comment: What do you mean by _"as mine is a repo and their is a direct resource call"_?

Comment: I was able to repro the issue for a moment. Though after several code changes (not relevant to the method with issue)  it went away. Either way the issues was refereeing to something in the base class (`DbContext`) so it seems that you (if you will be able to create a usable repro) to create an issue either in the infer repo or in the EF Core repo.